# sliding left content banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to create a flipping content banner. I manage to find one that is almost similar to what i want but there are still thing I want. Is it possible to make it auto play without the play button and make is to keep the effect of slide left when it reach the last slide back to the first. Is there anyone can help? I 
http://jsfiddle.net/4q3GZ/342/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = 300,
        width = 600,
        tabs = 3,
        $tabs = $('.tab'),
        contentNum = 1,
        delay = 2000, // time in milliseconds to pause between tabs
        timer;
    $('.play').click(function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        if($t.hasClass('playing')) {
            // stop
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $t.removeClass('playing').html('play');
        } else {
            // play
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                contentNum++; // change to contentNum--; to go left
                if(contentNum > tabs) {
                    contentNum = 1;
                } // loop right
                if(contentNum < 1) {
                    contentNum = tabs;
                } // loop left
                $tabs.eq(contentNum - 1).find('a').trigger('click');
            }, delay);
            $t.addClass('playing').html('stop');
        }
    });
    $('.main_inner').css({
        width: tabs * width
    });
    $('a.tab_link').click(function () {
        $tabs.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        // make sure contentNum is a number and not a string
        contentNum = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10);
        $('.main_inner').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + (width * contentNum - width)
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });
    $('.previous a').click(function () {
        if(contentNum > 1) {
            // find previous tab, trigger a click on the link
            // subtract 2 because eq() uses zero based index
            $tabs.eq(contentNum - 2).find('a').trigger('click');
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('.next a').click(function () {
        if(contentNum < tabs) {
            // find next tab, trigger a click on the link
            // contentNum doesn't need + 1 because it is +1 relative to eq()
            // which is a zero based index
            $tabs.eq(contentNum).find('a').trigger('click');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: did you write this code ?

Comment: search Google for a jquery slider..

Comment: `Is it possible to make it auto play without the play button` Seriously, just call your `click` function every few seconds.

Comment: The simplest would be just call `$('.play').click();`.

Comment: Nope I didnt write this script. I google it. I just a a beginner in learning javascript is it a bit hard for me to try to modifty the script and I m having a tough time to eevn try to under stand the solution you all are qiving

Answer (score 0):

The `#play` button has an event listener tied to an anonymous function that begins the content sliding process. Move that anonymous function out to a named function, and call it once your page has finished loading.

**However**, It is best to not rely on pre-packaged solutions like these, and instead, put in the effort into *understanding* how the code works. Do yourself a favour and learn how to do this without the help of googling scripts to copy and paste. Use online examples **only** as a reference.

Comment: Thanks For your help. But is it possible that slide keep on silding back to the first slide by silding left when it reach end?

Comment: Yes, but doing so is beyond the scope of the provided code, and it requires a more thorough understanding of javascript than I can provide in a Stack Overflow answer/comment. Search the web and research *every single line* in the code snippet you pasted above. Understand how each line works, and why it was coded in that specific way.

Comment: One possible way of achieving what you want would be to duplicate the data set so that you continually slide to the left, shuffling the two data sets so that the stack is essentially infinite.